# Windows shared folder access from a domain user to a non-domain user

Tags: windows, network-share

I have two computer, the first one is the server (so WinXP) with a shared folder granted for user "test" and this is out of domain, it is just in WORKGROUP.
The second computer is a client computer (WS2012) in domain and i would like to access directly to the shared folder of the server without prompting username/password.

I tried to add a "test" user (with the same password) in localuser of the client and also in the domain, but the access fails.

I need this on.the.fly access because i need some file from share just with a file path
(ex. \server\path\file.txt) without prompting.

thank you.

Comment: Why can't the server be a domain member?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. Create a local account on each machine with the exact same username and password. Have your batch job run as this account. Give this account permission to access the share. This is called pass-through authentication and it's an ugly hack and holdover from the early days.
2. Give [Everyone access and enable anonymous authentication](https://serverfault.com/q/272409/10472). This is *extremely* insecure and you shouldn't do this either.
3. The "correct" way to handle this is to join the server to the domain and use a domain account that has access to the share to run the batch job in question.

Comment: Point 1, so so dodgy. But it works a treat! My environment is AWS so a real nightmare. @MDMarra thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried authenticating with the test account, with username `COMPUTERNAME\Test` instead of just `Test` -- your Win2012 machine might be prepending its own domain name on to the username.

Comment: It works, but i want a permament access without prompting user/password