# Is there a way to create a share that does not require username/password when accessed all through the command line?

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, network-share, wmi

I know there's a way to do this from a GUI ([Setting up an anonymous Windows Server 2008 network share?](https://serverfault.com/questions/272409/setting-up-an-anonymous-windows-server-2008-network-share)), but I am writing a script so I want to see if you can do it without the GUI.

In other words, I want to create a share from the command line, and then be able to access that share from another box on the same network without the share prompting me for a username and password. I just want to be able to access it by doing `net use \\<boxhostingshare>\<sharename>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to PowerShell V4/WMF4 you can use new-smbshare. Information about new-smbshare found here: [New-SMBShare](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635722.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
New-SmbShare -Name "VMSFiles" -Path "C:\ClusterStorage\Volume1\VMFiles" -FullAccess "Everyone","Guests","Anonymous Logon"
```

If you need to create the folder first,

```
new-item "c:\clusterstorage\Volume1\VMfiles" -itemtype directory
```

[New-Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation.

Change folder names to the ones you require.

Thanks, Tim.